# Do i need to create a mapping model for every model version of my app

Tags: iphone, core-data

Just a quick question.

If i have 4 versions of my Core Data Model

Version 1.00, 1.01, 1.02 and the newest 1.03

Do i have to create a mapping model for each version to the latest

Example do i have to create 
1.00 -> 1.03
1.01 -> 1.03
(of course i have to create 1.02 -> 1.03

Or will it be fine if i have 1.00 -> 1.01 and 1.01 -> 1.02 and then now 1.02 -> 1.03

I can't seem to find anything by googling it, it's hard to know what search terms people would use

Answer (score 0):

Exactly when you need to use a mapping model is based on how many changes you make from version to version. If the accumulated changes are minor enough that automatic migration can handle them, then you don't strictly speaking need a mapping model.

However, using a mapping model for every version is always the safest option. It ensures that no matter how your needs change you can always guarantee that you have will always have a smooth and reliable upgrade path.

Comment: Ok so i would have to create a mapping model for 1.00 to 1.03 and every possible combination to make it reliable. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is safest but note that is for release version of the data model only. During development, you usually don't worry about it. Even in the release app, you only need to make a mapping model when you change the data model itself. I wouldn't advise going to overboard with mapping models. You also run the risk of introducing bugs if you do it to much.